# POSIX regex not compiling

Tags: c, regex, pattern-matching, posix, ip-address

I have this code for matching an IP address pattern. But it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. It always prints on the terminal "No match"

```
    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];
    reti = regcomp(&regex, "^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})$", 0);
    if (reti) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); 
        exit(1);
    }

    reti = regexec(&regex, "124.168.21.3", 0, NULL, 0);
    if (!reti) {
        puts("Match");
    } else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
        puts("No match");
    } else {
        regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        exit(1);
    }
    regfree(&regex);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, in fact I should specify the cflags field of the [regcomp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html) function to REG_EXTENDED and not 0.

Comment: +1 Yes, it seems that the `{1,3}` is causing the problem without that.

Comment: But you also must escape as I showed, otherwise you'll also match `124168213`.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the dots. And you probably don't need the capturing groups. Replace

```
"^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})$"
```

with

```
"^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}$"
```

Comment: No it didn't fix the problem, I still have a "No match" message on the terminal..